# Conditional based regex split in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split company name into Parent company and Alias company based on some conditions. I need some help in that.

**Original_Input**

```
DORO INC ( O/S DORO SAFETY & SECURITY)
MJB SUPPLY (DALIAN) CO., LTD.
Iris Diagnostics, a Division of Iris International Inc
GINGI-PAK a division of The Belport Co., Inc.
H/P/COSMOS SPORTS & MEDICAL GMBH
Arrayent Health LLC d/b/a/ Ambio Healthc
Arrow International, Inc. (subsidiary of Teleflex, Inc.)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Parent_Company                                              Alias_Name

1.DORO INC                                                  O/S DORO SAFETY & SECURITY
2.MJB SUPPLY CO., LTD.                                      DALIAN    
3.Iris Diagnostics, 
4.GINGI-PAK                                                 The Belport Co., Inc.
5.H                                                         P/COSMOS SPORTS & MEDICAL GMBH
6.Arrayent Health LLC                                       Ambio Healthc
7.Arrow International, Inc.
```

**My code:**

## Parent Company Split:

```
def get_parent_company(input):
keywords = ["a division of", "c/o","subsidiary of", "division of","an","dba","d/b/a","o/s","os","\/"]
regex = r"(.*?)(\b{}\b)".format("\\b|\\b".join(keywords))
matches = re.finditer(regex, input, re.IGNORECASE)
for match in matches:
    return match.group(1).strip()

data["Parent_Company"] = data["Original_Input"].apply(get_parent_company).fillna('')
```

## Alias company split:

```
pat = r'\((.*?)\)'
pat1 = r'(?:(?=[^\s/]*/(?!\s|[^\s/]*/))|\$|a division of|&|/\s)\s*(.*)'
if pat:
    data['Alias_Name'] = data['Original_Input'].str.extract(r'\((.*?)\)')
 if pat1:
    data['Alias_Name'] = data['Original_Input'].str.extract(r'(?:(?=[^\s/]*/(?!\s|[^\s/]*/))|\$|a 
                                              division of|&|/\s)\s*(.*)',expand= False).fillna('')
```

So here there are different types of input. Words before the keywords ("a division of", "c/o","subsidiary of", "division of","an","dba","d/b/a","o/s","os","/") has to be mentioned as parent company and words after that for some input as alias name.

Also there is another type of input Eg. MJB SUPPLY (DALIAN) CO., LTD. where (Dalian) is the alias name and remaining like MJB SUPPLY CO., LTD. is the parent name.

My Efforts:

Hence I tried to put a regex(with the help of some friends here in SO) with the keywords for obtaining parent name and alias name. But don't know how to put one or two conditions for the regex rather I can say that I don know how to split inputs of different types in the Data frame.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

```
%%time
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import string
from string import digits
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from io import StringIO
import re





#Creating engine to connect Py to SQL
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:// **:***'+server+'/'+database+'? 
driver=SQL+server')

#Reading SQL table and grouping by columns
df=pd.read_sql('select * from [dbo].[TempCompanyName]',engine)

#Creating Dataframe
#data=pd.DataFrame(df)

# removing numbers,duplicated spaces,spaces before or after the string
data['Cleansed_Input'] = data["Original_Input"].str.replace("[0-9]+", 
"").str.replace("[^\w ]+", "").str.replace(" +", " ").str.strip()

#Removing ASCII characters
data['Cleansed_Input'] = data['Cleansed_Input'].apply(lambda x:''.join(['' if 
ord(i) < 32 or ord(i) > 126 else i for i in x]))


#Method 2 in splitting:

class CompanyAlias(object):
    rules = [
        re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>[^\(]*)(\((? 
P<SUBSIDIARY>\s+subsidiary\s+.*)\))?(?P<SUFFIX>.*)", re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>[^\(]*)(\((?P<ALIAS>[^\)]+)\))?(?P<SUFFIX>.*)", 
re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>.*),?\s+a\s+division\s+of\s+(?P<DIVISIONOF>.*)", 
re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>.*)\s+d/b/a/\s+(?P<ALIAS>.*)", re.IGNORECASE),
    re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>[^/]+)/(?P<ALIAS>.*)", re.IGNORECASE)
]

@classmethod
def process_rules(cls, name, biz_rules=None):
    if biz_rules is None:
        biz_rules = cls.rules

    # process all the rules for the given name
    results = [r.match(name) for r in biz_rules]
    # keep only results that successfully matched a rule
    retval = [r.groupdict() for r in results if r]
    return retval

@classmethod
def process_results(cls, results):
    """Process results applies the desired business logic
    to the results obtained via regular expression processing
    1. Alias rules are priority 1
    2. division of rules are priority 2

    rankings element 0 is a list of all alias results in order of
    precedence. element 1 is a list of all division of rules in 
    order of precedence.

    Note: company names are always composed of SUFFIX + PREFIX
    """
    rankings = [[], []]
    retval = ("", "", "")
    for r in results:
        alias = r.get("ALIAS", "")
        divisionof = r.get("DIVISIONOF", None)
        company = "{0}{1}".format(r.get("PREFIX",""), r.get("SUFFIX",""))
        if alias:
            if re.search("subsidiary", alias, re.IGNORECASE):
                alias = ""
            rankings[0].append((company, alias.strip(), divisionof))
        if divisionof:
            rankings[1].append((company, alias, divisionof))

    # if there is at least 1 alias business rule applied
    # then return the first result from the alias rules
    # otherwise if there is at least 1 division of rule return
    # that.
    if len(rankings[0]) > 0:
        retval = rankings[0][0]
    elif len(rankings[1]) > 0:
        retval = rankings[1][0]

    return retval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    names = df["Original_Input"]

#print("{0:40s} Alias_Name".format("Parent_Company"))
#print()
for name in names:
    results = CompanyAlias.process_rules(name)
    result = CompanyAlias.process_results(results)
    #print("{0:40s} {1}".format(result[0], result[1]))
    df['Parent_company'] = result[0] 
    df['Alias_Name'] = result[1]
data=pd.DataFrame(df) 
#Writing to SQL
data.to_sql('TempCompanyName', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index= False)

#Splitting Company type and Extension.

engine.execute('''update A 
set A.Type_input = B.Company_Type 
from [TempCompanyName] A (nolock), [company_Extension]B  where  
A.Cleansed_Input like '%'+B.Name_Extension

update A 
set A.Core_Input =replace(A.[Cleansed_Input],B.Name_Extension,'')
from [TempCompanyName] A (nolock), [company_Extension]B  where  
A.Cleansed_Input like '%'+B.Name_Extension''')

engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)
```

Have hide the server details for security purpose

Comment: This data is too volatile to be parsed using regex normal size. You have to include lot of different conditions to find where to split companies. Even if you'll write expression which would parse this particular source, there's big chance that it'll stop to work on other data.

Comment: Omg. Is there any other way apart from using regex.

Comment: You've eited your question, now I'm not quite sure that my comment still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note:  This answer contains a lot of caveats

Unfortunately you have stumbled into the rabbit hole. Name cleansing and parsing is an industry unto itself. Depending on what business you are in, you may want to investigate companies that provide this type of service. I wish you all the luck in the world, as I have been tasked with this effort many times.

### Methodology

Create a series of prioritized business rules for identifying cases you see on a regular basis. As new edge-cases arise, simply more rules in the appropriate priority.

Prioritization is important as one rule may create a false positive. False Positive rules should have lower priorities than True Positive rules.

To illustrate this point, you have presented in your examples names with H/P/Cosmos and d/b/a which require different rules to identify. However, if the rule that identifies H/P/Cosmos is applied before the *doing-busines-as* rule, you will get a False Positive for the name containing d/b/a.

### Is this good enough?

Sets of data within individual sources tend to have a personality. There are similarities that appear in high frequencies and allow for the creation of business rules that get you 90% of the way to your goal.

### Tips

Try to avoid information loss when parsing your names. Identify Prefixes, Suffixes, Aliases, Subsidiaries and division and keep them for future resolution. Flag the suspicious records for review. This will allow you to identify new rules and prevent garbage from proceeding into the next phase of processing.

```
import re

class CompanyAlias(object):
    rules = [
        re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>[^\(]*)(\((?P<SUBSIDIARY>\s+subsidiary\s+.*)\))?(?P<SUFFIX>.*)", re.IGNORECASE),
        re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>[^\(]*)(\((?P<ALIAS>[^\)]+)\))?(?P<SUFFIX>.*)", re.IGNORECASE),
        re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>.*),?\s+a\s+division\s+of\s+(?P<DIVISIONOF>.*)", re.IGNORECASE),
        re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>.*)\s+d/b/a/\s+(?P<ALIAS>.*)", re.IGNORECASE),
        re.compile(r"(?P<PREFIX>[^/]+)/(?P<ALIAS>.*)", re.IGNORECASE)
    ]

    @classmethod
    def process_rules(cls, name, biz_rules=None):
        if biz_rules is None:
            biz_rules = cls.rules

        # process all the rules for the given name
        results = [r.match(name) for r in biz_rules]
        # keep only results that successfully matched a rule
        retval = [r.groupdict() for r in results if r]
        return retval

    @classmethod
    def process_results(cls, results):
        """Process results applies the desired business logic
        to the results obtained via regular expression processing
        1. Alias rules are priority 1
        2. division of rules are priority 2

        rankings element 0 is a list of all alias results in order of
        precedence. element 1 is a list of all division of rules in 
        order of precedence.

        Note: company names are always composed of SUFFIX + PREFIX
        """
        rankings = [[], []]
        retval = ("", "", "")
        for r in results:
            alias = r.get("ALIAS", "")
            divisionof = r.get("DIVISIONOF", None)
            company = "{0}{1}".format(r.get("PREFIX",""), r.get("SUFFIX",""))
            if alias:
                if re.search("subsidiary", alias, re.IGNORECASE):
                    alias = ""
                rankings[0].append((company, alias.strip(), divisionof))
            if divisionof:
                rankings[1].append((company, alias, divisionof))

        # if there is at least 1 alias business rule applied
        # then return the first result from the alias rules
        # otherwise if there is at least 1 division of rule return
        # that.
        if len(rankings[0]) > 0:
            retval = rankings[0][0]
        elif len(rankings[1]) > 0:
            retval = rankings[1][0]

        return retval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    names = [
        "DORO INC ( O/S DORO SAFETY & SECURITY)",
        "MJB SUPPLY (DALIAN) CO., LTD.",
        "Iris Diagnostics, a Division of Iris International Inc",
        "GINGI-PAK a division of The Belport Co., Inc.",
        "H/P/COSMOS SPORTS & MEDICAL GMBH",
        "Arrayent Health LLC d/b/a/ Ambio Healthc",
        "Arrow International, Inc. (subsidiary of Teleflex, Inc.)",
    ]
    print("{0:40s} Alias_Name".format("Parent_Company"))
    print()
    for name in names:
        results = CompanyAlias.process_rules(name)
        result = CompanyAlias.process_results(results)
        print("{0:40s} {1}".format(result[0], result[1]))
```

### Output

```
Parent_Company                           Alias_Name

DORO INC                                 O/S DORO SAFETY & SECURITY
MJB SUPPLY  CO., LTD.                    DALIAN
Iris Diagnostics,                        
GINGI-PAK                                
H                                        P/COSMOS SPORTS & MEDICAL GMBH
Arrayent Health LLC                      Ambio Healthc
Arrow International, Inc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I will try to do as you say. As per the code why some of the companies are not split. Like Eg. GINGI-PAK a division of The Belport Co., Inc. is  not getting split. Can you help .

Comment: Also can you explain the code a little so that I will be more clear.

Comment: @DhanalakshmiV, GINGI-PAK is indeed getting split. The examples you listed have conflicting business rules. Why does Iris Diagnostics not get an alias but GINGI-PAK get one? They are both "a division of". Therefore, I opted not to show an alias for companies that were listed as a division because expected output #3 didn't have one, but #4 did. The answer provided should allow you to manipulate business rules in any manner that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Kristian, just had a doubt. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: One more doubt @Kristian, I tried adding my input and output column to the code. I added the input column. But where do I have add my output columns. My o/p columns are df[Parent_Company], df[Alias_Name]

Comment: @DhanalakshmiV , the result variable is a list. Element 0 is Parent_Company and Alias_Name is element 1. Therefore df[Parent_Company] = result[0] and df[Alias_Name] = result[1]

Comment: Hi @Kristian, I did put the output columns, but then it is showing only one input's output in all columns. I put the input column df[Original_Input] beside names. that is if __name__ == "__main__":
    names =df[Original_Input]                                                                              
But am getting output for arrow international for all the columns, Can you help me out

Comment: @DhanalakshmiV you would need to post another question so I can see your code. The code I provided works. There must be a logic bug in your new code, which I can’t see unless you open another question.

Comment: I am trying to use your code only @Kristian. But trying to just add my input and output columns to it. Let me edit the question and add the code.

Comment: @DhanalakshmiV , Arrow International is the last name in the list. Is it perhaps where you are assigning your df column? Is it outside the loop per chance?

Comment: Hi @Kristian, I have added my code to the question. replcing with my input and output columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207760/discussion-between-dhanalakshmi-v-and-kristian).

Comment: Hello @Kristian, I tried following up with you twice but was not able to reach you. Please let me know when your available.

Comment: Hi @Kristian I replied in the chat, please let me know if your able to see it.

Comment: Hello @Kristian, Need a help in the above code. Am able to write into sql table. But then the code prints only the split data. If incase the input has no alias name then that should be put into the parent company column itself. Can you help me with how to do that. Splitting has to be done but if input has no alias name then that should go into the parent company